# Filter to exclude all traffic from all the sub-domains

Tags: google-analytics

I tried to create a view filter by excluding all the traffic from all sub-domains like *.mydomain.com in GA, my exclude filter pattern is like this "\Q*.mydomain.com\E" and seems not working. Because once the filter applied, it still showing visits from the sub-domains under the real-time active users right now home page.

Anyone knows how to do it, We have hundreds of sub-domains and don't want to create a filter for each one of them.

So the view only will include traffic is from the main domain - mydomain.com

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Real time is not accurate, if the filter is correct you will see cleaned data in the actual report.